# Unable to Convert JsonObject to JsonArray

Tags: android, json, android-json

I'm having problem while converting jsonObject to jsonArray

This is my Json string:

```
{"GetAllEmployeeResult":"[{\"firstName\":\"Super\",\"lastName\":\"User\",\"empID\":\"admin\",\"pswd\":\"2031189006230102079245048053200\",\"position\":null,\"contactNo\":null,\"backupCode\":null,\"email\":\"0\",\"hcode\":null,\"empStatus\":\"A\",\"createdBy\":null,\"dateAdded\":null,\"updatedBy\":null,\"dateUpdated\":null,\"profileID\":null,\"locationsID\":null,\"former\":null,\"secContact\":null,\"NoOfAttempts\":null,\"workstation\":null}]"}
```

I have verified this json with online tools and it is valid.

But when I try to it into JSONArray it give me this exception:

> org.json.JSONException: Value
>   [{"firstName":"Super","lastName":"User","empID":"admin","pswd":"056118220216006084031189006230102079245048053200","position":null,"contactNo":null,"backupCode":null,"email":"0","hcode":null,"empStatus":"A","createdBy":null,"dateAdded":null,"updatedBy":null,"dateUpdated":null,"profileID":null,"locationsID":null,"former":null,"secContact":null,"NoOfAttempts":null,"workstation":null}]
>   at GetAllEmployeeResult of type java.lang.String cannot be converted
>   to JSONArray

Following is my code:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("GetAllEmployeeResult");
```

*buffer hold JSON string

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because the value of `GetAllEmployeeResult` key is a `String`, not a `JSONArray`. There are double quotes surrounding the `JSONArray`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it like this

```
JsonArray array = new JsonArray(jObject.getString("GetAllEmployeeResult"));
```

Comment: I already did, but because I have reputation less than 15 so it didn't show up

Answer (score -1):

Using the Java API for JSON Processing，to convert an JsonObject to a JsonArray, you can also try below.

```
JsonArray array = Json.createArrayBuilder()
    .add(jObject)
    .build();
```